# MCP Unrecognized option: -Xincgc

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I decompiled 1.8.8 Minecraft with MCP and setup an Eclipse Workspace. After that I tried to run it but got

```
Unrecognized option: -Xincgc
```

Comment: You run Java with the `-Xincgc` option which is for older Java version to enable the inc(remental) g(arbage) c(ollector). Newer Java version do not support it anymore, using better garbage collector by default instead. So just remove `-Xincgc` from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

[@howlger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6505250/howlger) Suggested to remove the -Xincgc option when running Eclipse. To do so, go to `Run > Run Configurations > Arguments` then edit your options in the VM arguments section.

Answer (score 0):

The "mcp918" depends on which **version** of the Mod Coder Pack(*MCP*) you use

**mcp940.zip    = Minecraft client 1.12 & server 1.12**

**mcp937.zip    = Minecraft client 1.11.2 & server 1.11.2**

**mcp931.zip    = Minecraft client 1.10 & server 1.10**

**mcp928.zip    = Minecraft client 1.9.4 & server 1.9.4**

**mcp918.zip    = Minecraft client 1.8.8 & server 1.8.8**

**mcp908.zip    = Minecraft client 1.7.10 & server 1.7.10**

Go to the file location wherever you downloaded Mod Coder Pack (*MCP*)
and then follow this address"mcp918\eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core.launches" then open :-

> Client.Launch

with **notepad** or the **IDE** you prefer, remove the line that your error comes from, in this case *-Xincgc* :-

`<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.VM_ARGUMENTS" value="-Xincgc -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M"/>`

Even if you follow the steps, the game wont be able to run, due to errors that exist within the game's code, if you are able to fix these errors, you can run Mod Coder Pack(***MCP***)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ManjunathReddy is the improved answer **Less Broad**

Answer (score 0):

Change java run location to your installed java:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5xeXawYgK0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31423172)